# Automapper: How to leverage a custom INamingConvention?

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I am working with a database where the designers really seemed to enjoy capital letters and the underscore key. Since I have a simple ORM, my data models use these names as well. I need to build DTOs and I would prefer to give them standard names since we are exposing them through services. 
**The code below is now corrected! The test passes so use this as a reference if you need to use multiple naming conventions**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using AutoMapper;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    namespace AutomapperTest
    {
        public class DATAMODEL
        {
            public Guid ID { get; set; }
            public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
            public List<CHILD_DATAMODEL> CHILDREN { get; set; }
        }

        public class CHILD_DATAMODEL
        {
            public Guid ID { get; set; }
            public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
        }

        public class DataModelDto
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public List<ChildDataModelDto> Children { get; set; }
        }

        public class ChildDataModelDto
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public int OrderId { get; set; }
        }

        public class UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention : INamingConvention
        {
            private readonly Regex _splittingExpression = new Regex(@"[\p{Lu}0-9]+(?=_?)");

            public Regex SplittingExpression { get { return _splittingExpression; } }

            public string SeparatorCharacter { get { return "_"; } }
        }

        public class Profile1 : Profile
        {
            protected override void Configure()
            {
                SourceMemberNamingConvention = new UpperUnderscoreNamingConvention();
                DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
                CreateMap<DATAMODEL, DataModelDto>();
                CreateMap<CHILD_DATAMODEL, ChildDataModelDto>();
            }
        }
        [TestFixture]
        public class Tests
        {
            [Test]
            public void CanMap()
            {
                //tell automapper to use my convention
                Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<Profile1>());
                //make a dummy source object
                var src = new DATAMODEL();
                src.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
                src.FIRST_NAME = "foobar";
                src.CHILDREN = new List<CHILD_DATAMODEL>
                               {
                                   new CHILD_DATAMODEL()
                                       {
                                           ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                           ORDER_ID = 999
                                       }
                               };
                //map to destination
                var dest = Mapper.Map<DATAMODEL, DataModelDto>(src);
                Assert.AreEqual(src.ID, dest.Id);
                Assert.AreEqual(src.FIRST_NAME, dest.FirstName);
                Assert.AreEqual(src.CHILDREN.Count, dest.Children.Count);
                Assert.AreEqual(src.CHILDREN[0].ID, dest.Children[0].Id);
                Assert.AreEqual(src.CHILDREN[0].ORDER_ID, dest.Children[0].OrderId);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have very similar issue and can't figure it out. Basically want to map database generated code e.g customer_id to CustomerId and it doesn't work. Can you please post your full code for this test please? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your mappings in profiles, and define the `INamingConvention` parameters as appropriate.

I don't like the global/static, so I prefer using Initialize and define all of my mappings together.  This also has the added benefit of allowing a call to AssertConfiguration... which means if I've borked my mapping I'll get the exception at launch instead of whenever my code gets around to using the problematic mapping.

```
Mapper.Initialize(configuration =>
{
    configuration.CreateProfile("Profile1", CreateProfile1);
    configuration.CreateProfile("Profile2", CreateProfile2);
});
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

in the same class with that initialization method:

```
public void CreateProfile1(IProfileExpression profile)
{
    // this.CreateMap (not Mapper.CreateMap) statements that do the "normal" thing here
    // equivalent to Mapper.CreateMap( ... ).WithProfile("Profile1");
}

public void CreateProfile2(IProfileExpression profile)
{
    profile.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
    profile.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();

    // this.CreateMap (not Mapper.CreateMap) statements that need your special conventions here
    // equivalent to Mapper.CreateMap( ... ).WithProfile("Profile2");
}
```

if you do it this way, and don't define the same mapping in both profiles, I don't think you need anything to "fill in the blank" from the original question, it should already be setup to do the right thing.

Comment: You may want to grab the AutoMapper source and have a look at it since there's not a lot of good documentation available.  Particularly to the 2 implementations of INamingConvention in INamingConvention.cs

Comment: OK so what I am hearing is that you cannot set naming conventions on a specific Map, but you CAN set naming conventions on a separate profile. So the solution to above would be to create two separate profiles. Let me try that out. And yes I have read the source code a long time back but now it looks like I need to write my own INamingConvention. Thanks for the tip

Comment: DotNet Zebra: based on your suggestions I have attempted to refactor and use naming conventions. I failed. I updated the question above with an isolated code sample you can run to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: One very subtle but very important bug in your code, you're creating the maps in the global static instead of in the profile Configure method (change both Mapper.CreateMap calls to CreateMap, or this.CreateMap, and you should have a passing test and the desired result)

Comment: That was very subtle and very important indeed! You fixed it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
public class DATAMODELProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DATAMODEL, DATAMODEL>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DATAMODEL, SOMETHINGELSE>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DATAMODEL, DataModelDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FIRST_NAME))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ChildDataModels, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CHILD_DATAMODELS));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the route I am going but of course it defeats many of automapper's benefits. I'm in search of a property naming convention I can apply to the granularity of a specific map