# AutoMapper mapping Function to a Member's get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a Member named "Name" and I'm using AutoMapper to map between my ViewModel and my base Model. However, I also have a method named "GetName()" on a separate ViewModel which seems to be overriding my "Name" member's 'get' on the actual model.

I've since renamed the method to "GetFullName()" and this is no longer a problem.

This work-around works just fine, however, I would like to know what override in AutoMapper I can implement to let it know to not map function values like "GetName()" to a member's 'get'.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you show some code?

Comment: I think you need to implement an `INamingConvention` interface, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418317/automapper-how-to-leverage-a-custom-inamingconvention)

Answer (score 0):

You can override via:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Comment: Good call, the problem (and I should have stated this earlier) is I do not know where else in our code base this could occur. I'm afraid other members are being overwritten by methods and want to prevent that from happening.

Comment: There's no way to prevent that, other than to not name your methods confusingly. I wouldn't name things like this WITHOUT AutoMapper.