# AutoMapper map PascalCase to Upper Under

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to
PascalCase  Property( like => FirstName)
to Upper Under Property (like =>FIRST_NAME)
How can I do it

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497674/c-sharp-automapper-map-issue-with-upper-case-under-score

Comment: @HPSingh is correct, you need to write a custom naming convention.

Comment: thanks，I was wrong ,AutoMapper is not case sensitive ，but,I haven used Attribute  [TypeMapper(SourceType = typeof(Order))] on class ，it cause the configuration to fail .